# Добавление записей в таблицу SQLite без использования PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sqlite

возможно ли добавить данные в таблицу SQLite с помощью HTML формы?

Comment: либо ты работаешь только с клиентской частью, либо с серверной, либо объединяешь обе. SQLite серверная технология. Для тебя подойдут только 2 последний варианта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> без использования PHP

да, конечно возможно. можно написать соответствующий код на любом скриптовом языке, который поддерживает ваш http-сервер.

> с помощью HTML формы

нет, невозможно. для внесения изменений в файлы, находящиеся на вашем **сервере**, на нём же (сервере) должен быть выполнен какой-то скрипт (программа), который и внесёт необходимые вам изменения.